# python main function not returning the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, function

I have the below code which is not returning the dataframe created in the main module. Can someone help what could be the issue. If not in `main()` the function works fine. I am unsure on what is being missed here. I am testing this code in Jupyter notebook and trying to call **exceldf** in a new cell

```
import package as pkg

def main():
    list1, list2= pkg.somefunction()
    exceldf = pkg.functiontoloadexcelfiles.function(parameter1, parameter2)
```

I am expecting to see the data in `exceldf` however I get the error `"name 'exceldf' is not defined"`.

Edit :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_26012/684895253.py in <module>
----> 1 exceldf

NameError: name 'exceldf' is not defined
```

The above code runs fine when not wrapped in main function.

```
    list1,list2= pkg.somefunction()
    exceldf = pkg.functiontoloadexcelfiles.function(parameter1,parameter2)
    exceldf.head()
```

**The below fixed the issue**

```
import package as pkg

def main():

    global exceldf
    list1, list2= pkg.somefunction()
    exceldf = pkg.functiontoloadexcelfiles.function(parameter1, parameter2)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Where are you trying to access `execldf`? It it easier to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you're calling `main()` from a cell in your Jupyter notebook and expecting the variable `exceldf` to appear in global scope, then that's not going to work because this variable is local to `main`, so its dataframe will be destroyed since you don't return it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`exceldf` is only locally declared within `main()` so you must either declare `exceldf` as a global variable or return `exceldf` from the `main()` function.

```py
import package as pkg

def main():
    list1, list2= pkg.somefunction()
    exceldf = pkg.functiontoloadexcelfiles.function(parameter1, parameter2)
    return exceldf


exceldf = main()

exceldf.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

check your code a little more for instances of where exceldf is used, it seems like there is a use of it that is outside the scope of the main function where the value is allocated, it could just be a whitespace issue. do you call `exceldf.head()` after your main function like this?

```
def main():
    list1, list2= pkg.somefunction()
    exceldf = pkg.functiontoloadexcelfiles.function(parameter1, parameter2)

exceldf.head()
```

if so, the main function was never called and it has no return statement so the interpreter doesn't know about the `exceldf` name yet but you are trying to call it, maybe try something like this:

```
def create_excel_df():
    list1, list2= pkg.somefunction()
    exceldf = pkg.functiontoloadexcelfiles.function(parameter1, parameter2)
    return exceldf

exceldf = create_excel_df()
exceldf.head()
```

i changed the name of your `main` function to something more descriptive because `main` would only really ever be used to run a main loop in a program while you're using a jupyter notebook more like a data pipeline intented for one of runs instead of continuous execution